# Transforming a variable (with many data points close to the max and min) into uniform distribution?

Tags: r, dataset, transformation

I need to make some models in R and have some trouble with some of my predictors. They are distributed between 0 and 1, they give the percentage of landcover types. E.g. 0.3 means 30% of the area is covered by forest.

Here are a histogram and a density plot of one of them:

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XtqQ.png)
[density plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhUW5.png)

I want to transform these predictors towards a uniform distribution within R (it does not have to be perfect). I don't know what transformation to use since there are many data points close to the maximum and the minimum of them.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you need to do this - most statistical methods don't make demands about the distribution of the predictor variables - but

```
rank(x)/(length(x)+1)
```

will give you a new variable that's uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 (and is never exactly 0 or 1)